# Почему удаляется первая буква строки

Tags: c#

Код:

```
       Console.WriteLine("Вводите слова через Enter. Чтобы закончить нажмите Esc");
        do
        {
            string tempStr = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(tempStr);
        }
        while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
```

Нужно, чтобы по нажатию Esc производился выход из цикла while. Так и происходит, но если я, допустим, ввел "слово", то строка tempStr почему то становится "лово", причем если я до этого уже вводил что либо. Если убрать условие цикла то проблема уходит. Почему так происходит?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вы считываете первый символ следующего ввода здесь:

```
(Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Escape)
```

Comment: Я вот думал что проблема в этом. А как это можно исправить, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: @ezh Т.к. `Console.ReadLine` не понимает `Esc`, то использовать например пустую строку в качестве окончания ввода данных. Либо делать свой обработчик ввода, например: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31998769/5328783